# Setting a fake controller Session in base before the derived constructor is run?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inheritance

I am unit testing controller actions, so I have set up a fake httpContext that includes a fake session as a dictionary that I can populate.

However, as part of some refactoring, code in the constructor now calls into the session before I can populate the fake Session.

Is there a way to populate the base controller's Session object before the derived controller ctor runs and throws a NullReferenceException? Or will this code in the ctor need changing?

Comment: Did you do that using dependencie injection ? If not, i think this technique solves your problem.

Comment: There is DI, but this doesn't help in this situation as the Session is part of the base controller that is faked and can set once the object is constructed, rather than something to be injected. Injecting the Session object seems like overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the code in the ctor to use an `ISomeService` that calls the code that access the Session, this is easily fake-able.

As per @dnaack's comment, the concrete type can be injected in.